# So, out of these questions about 1960s Japanese TV, what would be a question for this SE?

Tags: discussion, questions

So, out of these questions about 1960s Japanese TV, what would be a question for this SE? Or should it be moved to History.SE or something?

From [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57050/what-was-the-tv-schedule-like-in-1960s-japan) deleted question.

1. What did they broadcast and when? I know there were some anime and
   live-action shows going on by the latter half of the decade.
2. How many shows were imported from other countries and how much was
       internally made?
3. Were there any movies broadcast?
4. Were there any 24-hour channels?

[This](http://www.nhk.or.jp/strl/aboutstrl/evolution-of-tv-en/p13.html) page from the NHK on the evolution of Japanese television isn't much help, unfortunately?

Comment: It seems what you are really asking (from the comments on the deleted question) is *"Where can I find information on television broadcasts in 1960s Japan"*...right?

Comment: @Paulie_D - Either that, or ask for the info directly, if I can.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on whether these should be asked in History but I'll add **my personal** thoughts on each question

> What did they broadcast and when? I know there were some anime and live-action shows going on by the latter half of the decade.

This is **too broad** and so off-topic

> How many shows were imported from other countries and how much was internally made?

I think this *slightly* narrower focused but still seems **too broad** for me.

> Were there any movies broadcast?
>
> Were there any 24-hour channels?

These would be **on-topic** as all they require is a sourced Yes/No answer.